# ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the new associated balance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is nothing terribly obvious to me as to why this code isn't working. It gives me the error when the `.new` method is called on one of my models (`Balance`).

There are no ActiveRecord callbacks whatsoever on the `Balance` model.

`seeds.rb`:

```
client = Client.create! name: "XYZ Client"
client.create_related_records # line 29
```

```
    def create_related_records
        self.balance = Balance.new # fails here (line 13)
        self.balance.create_related_records
        self.balance.save!
    end
```

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the new associated balance.
/home/blaine/my_rails_app/app/models/client.rb:13:in `create_related_records'
/home/blaine/my_rails_app/db/seeds.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

What the heck does this mean? Why is `.new` attempting to save anything? I thought it wasn't supposed to try to save anything?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing `balance = Balance.new` in your console? What does it give you?

Something like `#<Balance id: nil, client_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>` ?

So you just **initialize** a balance record, but don't **create** it.

That's not something what `seeds.rb` are used for...

And now you try to `create_related_records` for a `balance` that was initialized but not saved.

You want to **create** a balance

```
def create_related_records
    self.balance.create(amount: 0, account: "debit") # or whatever columns you have there
    self.balance.create_related_records
    self.balance.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the moment you assign something as a related instance, it tries to save it.

e.g. `self.balance = Balance.new # performs a save on assignment`

but instead I did:

```
balance = Balance.new
balance.blah = 'foo'
balance.save!
self.balance = balance # automatic save seems to occur here, this time it's valid and built already before doing the assignment.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with a model/resource "review" which was failing upon the creation of a new instance but without explicitly saving. The page had loaded fine in a previous version of ruby/bundler/active record (honestly don't know which), but after upgrade it failed because the review resource in my app belongs to a few other resources (instructor, reviewer, etc.) and when initiating the Review.new I had not yet designated those parent foreign keys (e.g. reviewer_id) for the new resource to belong to. By adding `optional:true` to the end of the belongs statement it resumed working like a charm.

> ```
> class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :instructor, optional: true
>   belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'reviewer_id', optional:true
>   belongs_to :lesson, optional: true
>   belongs_to :ticket, optional: true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have validations in `Balance` which are triggered on line 29. I suspect you would see something when inspecting `self.balance.errors`.